# Is there a way to call Inkscape from the CLI to crop a SVG file, but maintain the original bounding box?

Tags: svg, command-line-interface, inkscape

I have been using the following in my code (I'm using powershell):

`& "C:\BIN\Inkscape\bin\inkscape.exe" -o $NewFullFilePath -D $NewFullFilePath | Out-Null`

This works fantastically, but it modifies the viewbox of the resulting file. I'd like to have Inkscape resize the artwork to the exact bounds of the artboard / viewbox, leaving the original viewbox values in tact.

Is this possible? Can someone show me the way?

**Edit: Adding more information**

What I mean by "cropping" a SVG, is the removal of all dead space around the artwork and resizing if necessary to fill said dead space. But I don't what the resize operation to change the size of the artboard (SVG viewbox).

### Here is an example file:

[image]

If I open the file in Illustrator, I get this:

[image]

What I want, is this:

[image]

In both examples the viewbox (artboard) remains identical at 48x48px.

I thought that's what the Inkscape command was doing (`inkscape.exe" -o $NewFullFilePath -D $NewFullFilePath`), but it's not. It's giving me all sorts of different viewbox values for each "cropped" image.

I *think* what Inkscape is doing is resizing the page to the artwork as opposed to resizing the artwork to the page.

Hopefully this update clarifies what I meant before. If anyone knows a way to do this via CLI and Inkscape, or even another application, that would be great. The only necessity is that I need to be able to accomplish this with the command line, as the operation is scripted.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by Cropping? clipping with an object or fitting the page to the object? It would be better if you provide an example/illustration.

Comment: @s.ouchene I added a lot more detail to the OP. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: So you are trying to scale the object to fit the artboard not the reverse (i.e. fitting the page to the object)? if so, that operation is not unique, you have to fit it either horizontally or vertically. Since SVG is a text file you can retrieve the width/height of the artboard (page) and change the width/height of the object accordingly.